# Select option value not changing. Elden Ring Weapon damage comparer

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple damage comparer by getting the values of each dropdown option and telling the user which of the two weapons is better and the difference in damage. The problem is when I click the button it only takes the values that are already selected in the dropdown it never updates based on the options selected. Thanks for reading :).

```js
const weaponList1 = document.querySelector("#weapon-1__list");
let weaponList1Option = weaponList1.options[weaponList1.selectedIndex];
const weaponList2 = document.querySelector("#weapon-2__list");
let weaponList2Option = weaponList2.options[weaponList2.selectedIndex];
const compareButton = document.querySelector(".compare-button");
const damageNumber = document.querySelector(".damage-number");
const betterWeapon = document.querySelector(".better-weapon");

// const straightSwordDamages = {
//     longSword: 110,
//     shortSword: 102,
//     broadSword: 117,
//     lordswornStraightSword: 115,
//     lazuliGlinstoneSword: 79,
//     crystalSword: 106,
//     carianKnightsSword: 88,
//     swordOfNightAndFlame: 87,
//     swordOfStTrina: 107,
//     goldenEpitaph: 85,
//     caneSword: 96,
//     ornamentalStraightSword: 101,
//     weatheredStraightSword: 103,
//     WarhawkTalon: 101,
//     nobleSlenderSword: 101,
//     regaliaOfEochaid: 89
// }
function comparer(weapon1, weapon2) {
  weapon1 = parseInt(weaponList1Option.value);
  weapon2 = parseInt(weaponList2Option.value);
  console.log(weapon1, weapon2)
  let damage;
  // if (weapon1 > weapon2) {
  //     damage = weapon1 - weapon2;
  //     damageNumber.innerHTM = damage;
  //     betterWeapon.innerHTML = weaponList1Option.text;
  // } else if (weapon2 > weapon1) {
  //     damage = weapon2 - weapon1;
  //     damageNumber.innerHTML = damage;
  //     betterWeapon.innerHTML = weaponList2Option.text;
  // } else if (weapon1 === weapon2) {
  //     damageNumber.innerHTML = "0";
  //     betterWeapon.innerHTML = "Both Have The Same Damage"
  // }
}

compareButton.addEventListener("click", comparer)
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h1 id="main-title">Elden Ring Physical Damage Comparer</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="category-section">
      <h2 class="category-title">Select Your Category Of Weapon</h2>
      <select id="category-selector">
        <option value="">Straight Sword</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="weapon-section">
      <div id="weapon-1__container">
        <select id="weapon-1__list">
          <div id="straight-sword__list">
            <option value="110">Long Sword</option>
            <option value="102">Short Sword</option>
            <option value="117">Broad Sword</option>
            <option value="115">Lordsworn Straight Sword</option>
            <option value="79">Lazuli Glintstone Sword</option>
            <option value="106">Crystal Sword</option>
            <option value="88">Carian Knight's Sword</option>
            <option value="87">Sword Of The Night And Flame</option>
            <option value="107">Sword of St Trina</option>
            <option value="85">Golden Epitaph</option>
            <option value="96">Cane Sword</option>
            <option value="101">Ornamental Straight Sword</option>
            <option value="103">Weathered Straight Sword</option>
            <option value="101">Warhawk's Talon</option>
            <option value="101">Noble's Slender Sword</option>
            <option value="89">Regalia Of Eochaid</option>
          </div>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div id="weapon-2__container">
        <select id="weapon-2__list">
          <div>
            <option value="110">Long Sword</option>
            <option value="102">Short Sword</option>
            <option value="117">Broad Sword</option>
            <option value="115">Lordsworn Straight Sword</option>
            <option value="79">Lazuli Glintstone Sword</option>
            <option value="106">Crystal Sword</option>
            <option value="88">Carian Knight's Sword</option>
            <option value="87">Sword Of The Night And Flame</option>
            <option value="107">Sword of St Trina</option>
            <option value="85">Golden Epitaph</option>
            <option value="96">Cane Sword</option>
            <option value="101">Ornamental Straight Sword</option>
            <option value="103">Weathered Straight Sword</option>
            <option value="101">Warhawk's Talon</option>
            <option value="101">Noble's Slender Sword</option>
            <option value="89">Regalia Of Eochaid</option>
          </div>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="compare-button">
      <button>Compare Weapons</button>

    </div>
    <div class="comparison-section">
      <p>The difference in damage is <span class="damage-number"></span></p>
      <p>In favor of <span class="better-weapon"></span></p>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: That's because you are getting the selected options once at page load. You should get the selected option in your event handler.

Comment: ahhhh. Thank you. That makes sense